# install4j hide installation component based on variable

Tags: java, install4j

What I want is the following:
1 installer with two possible scenarios:

- scenario Full: offers user core, designer components
- scenario Lite: offers user only core (hides designer as a component)

I have can set them in a varfile but that still allows use to see and select.  How can I have a variable controll component visibility and install?

Thanks

Comment: @ingo-kegel any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the "Installation type" screen is for:

[image]

If you want the user to be able to customize the components after the screen in the "Installation components" screen, and hide some of the components, you have to add a "Run script" action to the "Installation type" screen where you do something like:

```
boolean hidden = "lite".equals(context.getVariable("sys.installationTypeId"));
context.getInstallationComponentById("123").setHidden(hidden);
```

This assumes that you have assigned the custom ID "lite" to your lite installation type and that the ID of the installation component that should be hidden is "123".